# How to create an alias for the each Enumerable method?

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to create an alias for the Enumerable `each`? For example, to have `my_each` method that is just an alias to the original `each`.

I have tried using `alias` with no success:

```rb
module Enumerable
  alias :my_each :each
end
```

I know I can define my own `my_each` method but I just want an alias so it behaves **exactly** as `each` when used on any enumerator.

Comment: It's not clear what you're expecting. What do you think your first line in your code does? It's returning an Enumerator. It enumerates over `[1,2,3]`. You can't use `my_each` with `(1..5)`, because it's already enumerating the array `[1,2,3]`.

Comment: "I have tried […] with no success" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. How *exactly* did you try it? *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: @JörgWMittag I have updated the question with an example of what I have tried and didn't work. Although there is already an accepted answer with an explanation of why that is not possible. Thanks for your feedback. Anyhow the problem is already solved that's why I marked the answer I got as accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
module Enumerable
  def my_each(*args, &block)
    each(*args, &block)
  end
end
p [1,2,3].my_each
# => #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3]:each>
p (1..5).my_each
# => #<Enumerator: 1..5:each>
```

You can't alias, because `each` is not actually a method in `Enumerable`, so there's nothing to alias. `Enumerable` expects each class that it is mixed into to provide it.